# Hpw to push a matrix into a given position of a 3-dimensional array in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the matrix `m` 5X5 and I want to push it to the first (1) position of the 3-dimensional array `me`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
m = rand([0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8], 5, 5)
me = zeros(Int, 5, 5, 3)
push!(me[:,:,1], m) # I am doing an error here!
```

Comment: Isn't this just `me[:, :, 1] .= m`?

Comment: @DNF Yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not pushing, but concatenation. `hcat` and `vcat` are special cases for two dimensions, but here you need the third, so the more general `cat`.

```
julia> me = reshape(1:(5*5*3), 5, 5, 3);

julia> cat(m, me, dims=3)
5×5×4 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 7  5  4  2  8
 8  7  7  8  1
 3  7  8  7  1
 3  8  0  6  4
 8  8  6  7  0

[:, :, 2] =
 1   6  11  16  21
 2   7  12  17  22
 3   8  13  18  23
 4   9  14  19  24
 5  10  15  20  25

[:, :, 3] =
 26  31  36  41  46
 27  32  37  42  47
 28  33  38  43  48
 29  34  39  44  49
 30  35  40  45  50

[:, :, 4] =
 51  56  61  66  71
 52  57  62  67  72
 53  58  63  68  73
 54  59  64  69  74
 55  60  65  70  75
```

You can't (efficiently) do this operation in-place since in general (for other than the last dimension), it would amount to many individual inserts at random places as opposed to few moves and copies (I reshaped `1:75` to visualize that).

It might be more efficient to use an array of matrices:

```
julia> me2 = [me[:, :, i] for i in axes(me, 3)]
3-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 6 … 16 21; 2 7 … 17 22; … ; 4 9 … 19 24; 5 10 … 20 25]
 [26 31 … 41 46; 27 32 … 42 47; … ; 29 34 … 44 49; 30 35 … 45 50]
 [51 56 … 66 71; 52 57 … 67 72; … ; 54 59 … 69 74; 55 60 … 70 75]

julia> pushfirst!(me2, m)
4-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [7 5 … 2 8; 8 7 … 8 1; … ; 3 8 … 6 4; 8 8 … 7 0]
 [1 6 … 16 21; 2 7 … 17 22; … ; 4 9 … 19 24; 5 10 … 20 25]
 [26 31 … 41 46; 27 32 … 42 47; … ; 29 34 … 44 49; 30 35 … 45 50]
 [51 56 … 66 71; 52 57 … 67 72; … ; 54 59 … 69 74; 55 60 … 70 75]
```

#### (Mostly of theoretical interest)

Alternatively in this specific case, since you actually work with the last dimension, you *could* do an actual copy/move by working on a vector:

```
julia> m3 = collect(1:75);

julia> prepend!(m3, m);

julia> A = reshape(m3, 5, 5, :)
5×5×4 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 7  5  4  2  8
 8  7  7  8  1
 3  7  8  7  1
 3  8  0  6  4
 8  8  6  7  0

[:, :, 2] =
 1   6  11  16  21
 2   7  12  17  22
 3   8  13  18  23
 4   9  14  19  24
 5  10  15  20  25

[:, :, 3] =
 26  31  36  41  46
 27  32  37  42  47
 28  33  38  43  48
 29  34  39  44  49
 30  35  40  45  50

[:, :, 4] =
 51  56  61  66  71
 52  57  62  67  72
 53  58  63  68  73
 54  59  64  69  74
 55  60  65  70  75
```

But now you have potentially opened a can of worms with sharing:

```
julia> prepend!(m3, m)
ERROR: cannot resize array with shared data
Stacktrace:
 [1] _growbeg!
   @ ./array.jl:946 [inlined]
 [2] _prepend!(a::Vector{Int64}, #unused#::Base.HasShape{2}, iter::Matrix{Int64})
   @ Base ./array.jl:1123
 [3] prepend!(a::Vector{Int64}, iter::Matrix{Int64})
   @ Base ./array.jl:1115
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[101]:1
```